# Odoo timesheet that overlap

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I'm using odoo 10... Current timesheet (hr_timesheet_sheet) structure is like that it can not overlap, because there is almost zero connection between analytic line and hr_timesheet_sheet except dates... 
I have tried following method:

I have created a new field in hr_timesheet_sheet named 'editing' and whole idea was to set it to the 1 when user edited the timesheet (there was a 3rd party button to start custom 'edit mode') and in analytic line i have checked where user_id == uid and editing = 1 -> get id from hr_timesheet_sheet and paste in sheet_id, once user saved the timesheet it would update to 0 again...
But following practice has failed, because after page reload, it would refused to set 'editing' to 1 while i was clicking button.

My code looks like this:

```
def xtr(self):

        self.env.cr.execute(""" UPDATE hr_timesheet_sheet_sheet SET editing = %s WHERE id = %s""" %(1,self.id))
```

this is a button code where user starts 'edit_mode'

```
def _compute_sheet(self):

        """Links the timesheet line to the corresponding sheet

        """

        for ts_line in self:

            if not ts_line.project_id:

                continue

            sheets = self.env['hr_timesheet_sheet.sheet'].search(

                [('editing', '=', 1),

                 ('employee_id.user_id.id', '=', ts_line.user_id.id),

                 ('state', 'in', ['draft', 'new'])])

            if sheets:

                # [0] because only one sheet possible for an employee between 2 dates

                ts_line.sheet_id_computed = sheets[0]

                ts_line.sheet_id = sheets[0]

        self.env.cr.execute(""" UPDATE hr_timesheet_sheet_sheet SET editing = %s WHERE user_id = %s AND editing = %s""" %(0,self._context.get('uid'),1))
```

this is the code for sheet_id calculation...

p.s when user created a new timesheet after page reload (that would overlap) old sheet_ids which was belonged to previous sheet erased.

Simply, question is how to make 2 timesheet overlap... or how to fix m

Comment: Just for your information: the sheets will be removed in later versions. Maybe you shouldn't put too much efforts in "fixing" them. IIRC you're not forced to use them in Odoo 10 for creating timesheets (single analytic lines).

Comment: well, im planning to go with odoo 10 for some time and the design of the sheets is so cool... i know that sheet is practically using analytic line as the host